# How can I create a template for a button with QtGui (python3.x)

Tags: class, python-3.x, button, grid, qtgui

I was wondering how to create an amount(that is taken from a user input) of the same type of buttons that can be controlled individually? I tried to use classes to do this, but it only creates a single button.

```
class GridBtn(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, self_global, x, y):
    super(GridBtn, self).__init__()
    self.button = QPushButton("0", self_global)
    self.move(x,y)

def change_val(self, val):
    self.button = QPushButton(val, self_global)

def returnx(self, x):
    return x

def returny(self, y):
    return y
```

That is the GridBtn class that the grid generator references.

```
    self.grid_x = 3
    self.grid_y = 3 #later changed to user input, just for testing

    for x in range(self.grid_x):
        for y in range(self.grid_y):
            for grid_btn in range(self.grid_y):
                print("test") #testing if works
                #need to fix this to make more efficient
                grid_btn = GridBtn(self, x*10, y*10) 
                self.button_grid_layout.addWidget(grid_btn.button,x,y)
```

This is trying to create a specific amount of buttons, but just creates one button, like this: [image: window]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were calling on a subfunction above the one you needed to xd